# GestureRecognizer inside Streambuilder doesn't update snapshot.data

Tags: flutter, dart

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
  stream: _bloc.urlStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
  // 1.) url is NOT null here, expected value
  final url = snapshot.data;
  return RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      children: [
        // ...
        TextSpan(
          text: "...",
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: ThemeColor.lottoRed,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 14,
          ),
          recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
            ..onTap = () {
              // 2.) url is null here
            },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}),
```

The StreamBuilder gets its snapshot data correctly. It fires twice. The first time `snapshot.data` is null, the second time it has the expected value (Comment 1.)). If I click on the TextSpan's `GestureRecognizer`, the `url` is still null (Comment 2.)). The value doesn't get updated here, how can I solve this?

If I use a button and click it, it works, can somebody tell the difference. I have to use a TextSpan

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
  stream: _bloc.deregisterUrlStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    final url = snapshot.data;
    
    return CustomButton(
      action: () {
        // url NOT null here, works!
      },
      text: "testbutton"
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: did you try checking `snapshot.connectionState`  and only execute your code (return `TextSpan`) if its value is `ConnectionState.done`?

Comment: @最白目 I tried reproducing your code, and the error is not reproducible. Copying and pasting your code, changing your stream for Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (index) => index.toString()); has worked no problem, so it is not a problem of TextSpan

Comment: Thats interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is the chained onTap.

Creating a TapGestureRecognizer as variable and then setting the onTap if the snapshot hasData works.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation and code wasn't very clear to me because you didn't use *url* and couldn't figure it out how you'll ask for new data.
Here in the code bellow I used your code and made an example, hope it helps.

There is a counter and a stream, stream and counter are initiated by one and each time the user click on the text, the counter is increased by one and text shows the new number.

For stream, while it isn't fetch yet, it returns null and when data is fetched completely it return it.
You can handle different connection states by `snapshot.connectionState` inside a switch or simply just handle two cases, having data or not.

Also you could wrap your `RichText` inside other widgets like `GestureDetector()`.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamController<String> stream;
  int counter;
  @override
  void initState() {
    counter = 1;
    stream = StreamController<String>()..sink.add(counter.toString());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _widget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _widget() {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: stream.stream,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        return (snapshot.hasData)
            ? RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: snapshot.data,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        fontSize: 50,
                      ),
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () => stream.sink.add((++counter).toString()),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    stream.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```